# pandas groupby and join lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df, with two columns, I want to groupby one column and join the lists belongs to same group, example:

```
column_a, column_b
1,         [1,2,3]
1,         [2,5]
2,         [5,6]
```

after the process:

```
column_a, column_b
1,         [1,2,3,2,5]
2,         [5,6]
```

I want to keep all the duplicates. I have the following questions:

- The dtypes of the dataframe are object(s). convert_objects() doesn't convert column_b to list automatically. How can I do this?
- what does the function in df.groupby(...).apply(lambda x: ...) apply to ? what is the form of x ? list?
- the solution to my main problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`object` dtype is a catch-all dtype that basically means not int, float, bool, datetime, or timedelta. So it is storing them as a list. `convert_objects` tries to convert a column to one of those dtypes.

You want

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]: 
   a          b    c
0  1  [1, 2, 3]  foo
1  1     [2, 5]  bar
2  2     [5, 6]  baz


In [64]: df.groupby('a').agg({'b': 'sum', 'c': lambda x: ' '.join(x)})
Out[64]: 
         c                b
a                          
1  foo bar  [1, 2, 3, 2, 5]
2      baz           [5, 6]
```

This groups the data frame by the values in column `a`. Read more about [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

This is doing a regular list `sum` (concatenation) just like `[1, 2, 3] + [2, 5]` with the result `[1, 2, 3, 2, 5]`

Comment: thanks, I have another question: what if I have a third column that is string type, and I want to ' '.join them by column one's group. What should I do?

Comment: Strings are like lists of characters. So `.sum()` should work there as well.

Comment: Yes, but I want a ' ' (whitespace) between each concatenated string.

Comment: I hope i can upvote more, thank! that lambda function is applied on lists? [ 'foo', 'bar'], and ['baz'] ?

Comment: why not just `'c': ' '.join`

Answer (score 25):

```
df.groupby('column_a').agg(sum)
```

This works because of operator overloading `sum` concatenates the lists together. The index of the resulting df will be the values from `column_a`:

Comment: Nice solution (realizing after 7 years). A corollary observation: when `sum`ming up lists _and_ numbers at the same time, the single `.agg(sum)` only sums up the numeric cols. In that case the dictionary `{'a': sum, 'b': sum}` --thanks @TomAugspurger-- works perfect !

Answer (score 7):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23794283/16343464) suggests to use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), which is working fine with small number of lists, however using sum to concatenate lists is **quadratic**.

For a larger number of lists, a **much faster option** would be to use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) or a list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_a': ['1', '1', '2'],
                   'column_b': [['1', '2', '3'], ['2', '5'], ['5', '6']]})
```

`itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
out = (df.groupby('column_a', as_index=False)['column_b']
         .agg(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)))
       )
```

list comprehension:

```
out = (df.groupby('column_a', as_index=False, sort=False)['column_b']
         .agg(lambda x: [e for l in x for e in l])
      )
```

output:

```
  column_a         column_b
0        1  [1, 2, 3, 2, 5]
1        2           [5, 6]
```

##### Comparison of speed

Using n repeats of the example to show the impact of the number of lists to merge:

```
test_df = pd.concat([df]*n, ignore_index=True)
```

[image: comparison pandas list merge groupby]

*NB. also comparing the [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) approach (`agg(lambda x: np.concatenate(x.to_numpy()).tolist())`).*

Answer (score 3):

The approach proposed above using `df.groupby('column_a').agg(sum)` definetly works. However, you have to make sure that your list only contains `integers`, otherwise the output will not be the same.

If you want to convert all of the lists items into integers, you can use:

```
df['column_a'] = df['column_a'].apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy and simple "for" or "map":

`import numpy as np`

```
u_clm = np.unique(df.column_a.values)
all_lists = []

for clm in u_clm:
    df_process = df.query('column_a == @clm')
    list_ = np.concatenate(df.column_b.values)
    all_lists.append((clm, list_.tolist()))
```

`df_sum_lists = pd.DataFrame(all_lists)`

It's faster in 350 times than a simple "groupby-agg-sum" approach for huge datasets.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, helped me
`merge.fillna("", inplace = True) new_merge = merge.groupby(['id']).agg({ 'q1':lambda x: ','.join(x), 'q2':lambda x: ','.join(x),'q2_bookcode':lambda x: ','.join(x), 'q1_bookcode':lambda x: ','.join(x)})`