# pandas groupby: aggregating lists with a tuple index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This question is similar to one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794082/pandas-groupby-and-join-lists), but with a tuple index.
Grouping a column of lists works fine for a single index:

```python
mydata = [{'idx': 'A', 'list_str': ['hi', 'babe']},
          {'idx': 'A', 'list_str': ['take', 'a', 'walk']},
          {'idx': 'A', 'list_str': []},
          {'idx': 'B', 'list_str': ['on', 'the', 'wild', 'side']}]


df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
grouped = df.groupby('idx') 
print(grouped.agg({'list_str': lambda x: tuple(x)}))
```

With the expected output:

```
idx     list_str
A       [hi, babe, take, a, walk]
B       [on, the, wild, side]
```

However, adding a second index no longer works:

```python
mydata = [{'idx': 'A', 'idx2': 'B', 'list_str': ['hi', 'babe']},
          {'idx': 'A', 'idx2': 'B', 'list_str': ['take', 'a', 'walk']},
          {'idx': 'A', 'idx2': 'B', 'list_str': []},
          {'idx': 'B', 'idx2': 'C', 'list_str': ['on', 'the', 'wild', 'side']}]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
grouped = df.groupby(('idx', 'idx2'))
print(grouped.agg({'list_str': sum}))
```

Gives a `ValueError`, `Function does not reduce`.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To group by multiple columns use a list:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['idx', 'idx2'])
print(grouped.agg({'list_str': sum}))
```

Possibly you thought you were doing:

```
df['new_index'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['idx'],row['idx2']), axis=1)
df.set_index('new_index',inplace=True)

grouped = df.groupby(df.index)
print(grouped.agg({'list_str': sum}))
```

Comment: Have you tried the code? this actually gives the same exact error.

Comment: I did try it, using exactly the input you provided. Did you use a list `[]` instead of a tuple `()` in the groupby call? Or is your input data mis-constructed in that it has two separate indices instead of a single index of tuples?

Comment: using the same 'mydata' variable, and `df = pd.DataFrame(mydata); grouped = df.groupby(['idx', 'idx2']); print(grouped.agg({'list_str': sum}))` gives the same error using pandas version 0.19.2.