# If pandas merge finds several matches, write values rows into one field

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I had no real good idea how to formulate a good header here.

The situation is that I have two data frames I want to merge:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'ID'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2], [3, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['ID', 'values'])
```

so I do a:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID", how="left")
```

which results in:

```
   A   ID    values
0  1   2     NaN
1  1   3     2.0
2  1   3     3.0
3  4   6     NaN
```

What I would like though is that any combination of A and ID only appear once. If there were several ones, like in the example above, it should take the respective values and merge them into a list(?) of values. So the result should look like this:

```
   A   ID    values
0  1   2     NaN
1  1   3     2.0, 3.0
2  4   6     NaN
```

I do not have the slightest idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID", how="left") \
           .groupby(['A', 'ID'])['values'] \
           .apply(list) \
           .reset_index()
```

as in asongtoruin fine answer, but you might want to consider the case of only `None` as special (due to the merge), in which case you can use

```
    >>> df['values'].groupby([df.A, df.ID]).apply(lambda g: [] if g.isnull().all() else list(g)).reset_index()
    A   ID  values
0   1   2   []
1   1   3   [2.0, 3.0]
2   4   6   []
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. In addition to your answer, I also found this link helpful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794082/pandas-groupby-and-join-lists)

Comment: This is a neat answer, and definitely extends mine nicely! I think you might be able to replace the `len(g) == 1 and np.isnan(list(g)[0])` with `g.isnull().all()` to make it a more `pandas`-y answer

Answer (score 3):

Once you've got your merged dataframe, you can `groupby` columns `A` and `ID` and then simply apply `list` to your `values` column to aggregate the results into a list for each group:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['A', 'ID'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2], [3, 3], [4, 6]], columns=['ID', 'values'])

merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID", how="left") \
           .groupby(['A', 'ID'])['values'] \
           .apply(list) \
           .reset_index()

print(merged)
```

prints:

```
   A  ID      values
0  1   2       [nan]
1  1   3  [2.0, 3.0]
2  4   6       [nan]
```

Comment: I was just about to accept your answer, when @Ami Savory posted his answer, which comes even closer to what I needed.

Comment: This is a very good answer. @SLglider I really don't mind if you accept this one instead.