# Where to incorporate goup by to export correctly json?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm looking to export my DF to Json in a specific format, however I can't get the group-by right and I'm at a loss where to include it.

Dataframe:

```
  item_type  purch_price sale_price         city    location
0    Iphone         1200       1150          NaN         NaN
1  Computer          700        NaN  Los Angeles  1st street
2  Computer          700        NaN     San Jose  2nd street
```

**Current code:**

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'filepath', delimiter=';', header=0)

df = df.fillna('')

def shop_details(row):
    if row['city'] != '' and row['location'] !='':
        return [{'city': row['city'], 'location': row['location']}]
    else:
        return []

df['shop_details'] = df.apply(lambda row: shop_details(row), axis = 1)

df = df.drop(['city', 'location'], axis = 1)

def print_json(text):
    parsed = json.loads(text)
    print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=False))

print_json(df.to_json(orient='records'))
```

*** Current Result ***

```
[
    {
        "item_type": "Iphone",
        "purch_price": 1200,
        "sale_price": 1150.0,
        "shop_details": []
    },
    {
        "item_type": "Computer",
        "purch_price": 700,
        "sale_price": "",
        "shop_details": [
            {
                "city": "Los Angeles",
                "location": "1st Street"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_type": "Computer",
        "purch_price": 700,
        "sale_price": "",
        "shop_details": [
            {
                "city": "San Jose",
                "location": "2nd Street"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[{
    "item_type": "Iphone",
    "purch_price": "1200",
    "sale_price": "1150",
    "shop_details": []
  },
  {
    "item_type": "Computer",
    "purch_price": "700",
    "sale_price": "600",
    "shop_details": [{
        "city": "Los Angeles",
        "location": "1st street"
      },
      {
        "city": "San Jose",
        "location": "2nd street"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

- As seen in the example, I'd like the city and location information to be showed in the 'desired_output' format, rather than having two entries with the full item_type, purchase_price and sale_price.

Comment: Alternatively I have this code that groups correctly, but of which the output is not correct:

g_df = (df.
        groupby(['item_type', 'purch_price', 'sale_price'])["city", "location"].
        apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='records')).
        reset_index(name='shop_details'))

Comment: Where is `"sale_price": "600"` coming from in your desired output? I don't see that in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

After you drop the columns, use groupby with 'sum' to concatenate your list of dicts (another simpler example for concatenating lists: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794082/pandas-groupby-and-join-lists)) and then reset the index:

```
df_grouped=df.groupby(by=['item_type','purch_price','sale_price']).agg({'shop_details':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

The resulting output of your print_json is then:

```
[
{
    "item_type": "Computer",
    "purch_price": 700,
    "sale_price": "",
    "shop_details": [
        {
            "city": "'Los Angeles'",
            "location": "'1st street'"
        },
        {
            "city": "'San Jose'",
            "location": "'2nd street'"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "item_type": "Iphone",
    "purch_price": 1200,
    "sale_price": 1150.0,
    "shop_details": []
}
]
```

Note that I'm not sure where your sale price of 600 comes from as it's not in your original dataframe.