# Pandas groupby() merge different lists of strings

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm having the following dataframe.

| Fruit | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | ["red", "big"] |
| Banana | ["yellow", "long"] |
| Banana | ["elongated, twisted"] |
| Peach | ["round"] |
| Apple | ["round", "greenish"] |

And I'm trying to group by the descriptions according to the fruit, through a concatenation of the lists.
I should obtain that:

| Fruit | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | ["red", "big", "round", "greenish"] |
| Banana | ["yellow", "long", "elongated, twisted"] |
| Peach | ["round"] |

I followed the solution provided here: [pandas groupby and join lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794082/pandas-groupby-and-join-list):

```
df = df.groupby('Fruit', as_index=False).agg(Description =('Description', 'sum'))
```

but what I'm obtaining are lists attached to each other:

| Fruit | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | ["red", "big"]["round", "greenish"] |
| Banana | ["yellow", "long"]["elongated, twisted"] |
| Peach | ["round"] |

Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like your `Description` values are Strings, instead of Lists. Have you checked its data type ?

Comment: It was indeed the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `Description` column is string. You can strip out the `[]` and sum:

```
 '[' + df['Description'].str[1:-1].groupby(df['Fruit']).agg(', '.join) + ']'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to keep this list format? Is it possible?

Comment: Worded like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep your list format, I would suggest running a command before yours:

```py
import json
df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(json.loads)
df = df.groupby('Fruit', as_index=False).agg(Description =('Description', 'sum'))
```

That way, your values in the `Description` columns would be actual lists, and not strings.

Comment: When trying your solution, I'm having the following error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: It means one of your `Description` values doesn't follow the pattern [a, b, c, d, ...]