# I need to groubpy/aggregate with adding a comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to aggregate in this data frame columns.

```
data = {'one':['one', 'five', 'one', 'one'],
        'two':['one', 'five', 'one', 'one']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Using the following code:

```
new_df = df.groupby('one').agg(names = ('two', 'sum'))
```

The output will be:

```
five    five
one     oneoneone
```

How to add a comma between the aggregated results?

The wanted result:

```
five    five
one     one, one, one
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas groupby and join lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794082/pandas-groupby-and-join-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `','.join` instead of `sum`.

```
 new_df = df.groupby('one').agg(names = ('two', ', '.join))
```

Output:

```
             names
one 
five          five
one   one, one, one
```

Comment: Amazing. I learn a lot with you Rajan. Thank you.

Comment: @LanaStance if its helpful please mark as solution. Thanks

Comment: for sure I was going to. But the site does not allow me before 10 minutes ago.