# Groupby specific to list of concatenated items

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Let it be the following Python Panda DataFrame:

```
| ID   | time    | vector       | other |
| ---- | ------- | ------------ | ----- |
| 0    | 81219   | [N1, N2, N3] | blue  |
| 0    | 32323   | [N1, N4]     | green |
| 1    | 423     | [N2, N3]     | red   | 
| 1    | 4232    | [N1]         | blue  |
| 1    | 42424   | [N2, N2]     | red   |
| 2    | 42422   | [N3, N5]     | blue  |
```

I want to create a grouped DataFrame containing for each ID a column vector with the concatenation of the vectors for each element.

Example of the result:

```
| ID   | vector               |
| ---- | -------------------- |
| 0    | [N1, N2, N3, N1, N4] |
| 1    | [N2, N3, N1, N2, N2] | 
| 2    | [N3, N5]             |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas groupby and join lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794082/pandas-groupby-and-join-lists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option could be to use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
out = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['vector'].sum()
```

However, if you have many lists, a repeated sum will be quadratic.

In this case, prefer to use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
out = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['vector']
         .agg(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)))
       )
```

output:

```
   ID                vector
0   0  [N1, N2, N3, N1, N4]
1   1  [N2, N3, N1, N2, N2]
2   2              [N3, N5]
```

##### timing

Let's use 10k repeats of the example and compare `sum` and `itertools.chain`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                   'vector': [['N1', 'N2', 'N3'], ['N1', 'N4'], ['N2', 'N3'],
                              ['N1'], ['N2', 'N2'], ['N3', 'N5']]})
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

%%timeit
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['vector'].sum()
# this is very slow!
# 1.86 s ± 38.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
from itertools import chain
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['vector'].agg(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x)))
# much faster!
# 8.02 ms ± 359 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```